# Problem regarding particular integral based on other ODEs

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

If $\phi_1(x)$ is a particular integral of $Ly=\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}-a\dfrac{dy}{dx}+by=e^{ax}+f(x)$ and  $\phi_2(x)$ is a particular integral of $Ly=x^{ax}-f(x)$;a,b being constants, then a particular integral, of $Ly=2be^{ax}$ is

When specific values of a and b and f(x) are not given, it seems that some basic principle is required here.

The given answer is $\phi_1(x)-b\phi_2(x)$.

I don't how to go on about finding this answer or any answer for that matter. Is there some trick/shortcut involved here ?

Please help.